# Why a:active pseudo class does not working

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

Am using css for some site. I noticed that the a:active style definition in my css file does not work at all. I was told by someone that I have to put the definitions in this order

```
a:link {...}
a:visited {...}
a:hover {...}
a:active {...}
```

I have done so but it's still not working. Please could someone tell me why it is not working and a possible workaround. Thanks

Comment: What browsers and what is your css for the link(hint a jsfiddle link would be useful)?

Comment: We can't tell you because we're not the browser. Show your HTML, show your actual CSS. Provide a link we can use to test or debug your problem.

Comment: You need to provide the code, not just edit the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/BMHUz/

Click and hold on the anchor tag and you will see it turn orange.

Answer (score 2):

a:active just stay for the few milliseconds you are clicking the link.

May i ask what you expect to see? In case you want a link to be a different color if you are on that page, thats not what a:active is for

Answer (score 0):

If you want a link to be a different style if you are on that page, then you need to use jquery or javascript to change the style of active link.

jquery

```
$('a[href="' + window.location.href + '"]').addClass('active');
```

CSS

```
a.active{
    /* your CSS for active link */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `!important` to the property if it is already defined to the anchor.

```css
a {
    color: white;
}

a:active {
    color: black !important;
}
```